# How to consume remoting in IronRuby

Tags: remoting, ironruby

I was trying to consume a remoting service in IronRuby and I get this error.

Attempted to call a method declared on type 'IronRuby.Runtime.IRubyObject' on an object which exposes 'Contracts.SomeManager'.

Can you help me with this?

Here's my code.

```
require "netincludes"

some_manager = System::Activator.get_object ISomeManager.to_clr_type, "tcp://localhost:8080/SomeManager"
some_manager.get_message "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar (binding error actually) when attempting to cook up a simple IronRuby remoting example, but I could have botched my example, I haven't played with remoting much. 
Could you post the full code (along with netincludes) here (or somewhere)

Perhaps we can identify a bug (or implementation in progress) and add to the [codeplex issue tracker for IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/WorkItem/List.aspx).

I'll edit my answer here if it turns out not to be a bug, and I can help you resolve this.